# Flask: AttributeError: module 'http.client' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, flask

I installed flask and run a code as a below:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

After running this code, and opening localhost, I received this error:

```
conntype = self.headers.get('Connection', "")
AttributeError: module 'http.client' has no attribute 'get'
----------------------------------------
```

I reinstalled venv, reinitiated the project but nothing worked. what should I do?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with python 3.8.5 and flask 1.1.2, what version of python and flask are you using?

Comment: @tiega Python 3.7.2 Flask 1.1.2 Werkzeug 1.0.1

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you get any help?

Comment: @Tung unfortunately no.

Comment: @AmirhoseinShirani I have to upgrade python to 3.8.5. It helps resolve the problem. Could you try this approach?